# understanding pipes in UNIX

Tags: unix, pipe

I recently started reading about pipes. I didn't understand how it's printing the file descriptor numbers as 4 and 3 in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
int pfds[2];
char buf[30];
if (pipe(pfds) == -1) {
perror("pipe");
exit(1);
}
printf("writing to file descriptor #%d\n", pfds[1]);
write(pfds[1], "test", 5);
printf("reading from file descriptor #%d\n", pfds[0]);
read(pfds[0], buf, 5);
printf("read \"%s\"\n", buf);
return 0;
}
```

> output:
> writing to file descriptor #4
>
> reading from file descriptor #3
>
> read "test"

Here why/how is it printing 4 and 3?

Comment: What are you expecting them to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File descriptors are allocated as the smallest available. 0, 1, and 2 are already taken when the application starts (they inherit stdin, stdout, and stderr), so the next two descriptors you make will be 3 and 4.

Comment: Is this implementation dependent?  It seems to be true on the handful of OSs I've used, I'm curious if that's convention or standard or luck.

Comment: @cschneid: The POSIX specification for [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)
 says: _The open() function shall return a file descriptor for the named file that is the lowest file descriptor not currently open for that process._  It is required behaviour on POSIX-conformant systems.